# How to fix Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set error?

Tags: laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.7 I try to implement youtube video using this https://www.sitepoint.com/displaying-youtube-videos-php/
article.
I added my client id/secret in my .env and made using of them in config/google.php.
After in app/Http/Kernel.php file I added     GoogleLogin Middleware so running my app I got error :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()
```

That is printscreen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tStal.jpg

That is full error description :

```
[2018-11-29 05:58:04] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set() {"userId":50,"email":"ivancsvetkov@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Session\\Store::set() at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php:146)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(223): Illuminate\\Support\\Manager->__call('set', Array)
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/app/Services/GoogleLogin.php(36): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('set', Array)
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/app/Http/Middleware/GoogleLogin.php(18): App\\Services\\GoogleLogin->isLoggedIn()
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): App\\Http\\Middleware\\GoogleLogin->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(75): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(684): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#25 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(659): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#27 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(614): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/themsaid/laravel-mail-preview/src/MailPreviewMiddleware.php(19): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Themsaid\\MailPreview\\MailPreviewMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/src/RemoteValidationMiddleware.php(53): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\RemoteValidationMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(65): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#50 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#53 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#54 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/itsgoingd/clockwork/Clockwork/Support/Laravel/ClockworkMiddleware.php(29): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Clockwork\\Support\\Laravel\\ClockworkMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#56 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#57 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#58 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#59 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#60 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 {main}
"}
```

Googling I found that it is issue of early 5 laravel versions and advices like:

Replacing

```
 \Session::set('u2f.registerData', $req);
```

WIth

```
session(['u2f.registerData' => $req]);
```

OR

```
set -> put
```

But as file with error is inside of /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate I do not know what have I to edit and how to fix this error ?

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "aloha/twilio": "^4.0",
        "arrilot/laravel-widgets": "^3.12",
        "askedio/laravel-ratchet": "^5.6",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.5",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "5.x",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^3.0",
        "jrean/laravel-user-verification": "^7.0",
        "elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "mews/captcha": "^2.2",
        "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": ">2.2.0",
        "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "^0.19.1",
        "snowfire/beautymail": "dev-master",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.1",
        "spatie/laravel-tags": "^2.1",
        "themsaid/laravel-mail-preview": "^2.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "^1.9",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^8.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.2",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^2.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],


        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan vendor:publish --provider=\"Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\JsValidationServiceProvider\" --tag=public --force"
        ]

    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Thanks!